# How to know the most efficient way of finding the rank of matrix and how do I apply it to this example

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

For the matrix  $
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -3 \\ 1 & -2 & 3 \\ 4 & 8 & -12 \\ 1 & -1 & 5 \end{bmatrix}
$

The reduced row echelon I obtained is   $
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$

However, the answer is that the rank of this matrix is 2. How do I know if the rank is indeed 2?

Comment: It's a typo in the book.  You have computed the rref correctly, and the rank is therefore $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Doing Gaussian Elimination, you get
$$
\begin{split}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  2 &  -3 \\
1 & -2 &   3 \\
4 &  8 & -12 \\
1 & -1 &   5
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  2 &  -3 \\
0 &  4 &  -6 \\
0 &  0 &   0 \\
0 & -3 &   8
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  2 &  -3 \\
0 &  1 &  -3/2 \\
0 &  0 &   0 \\
0 & -3 &   8
\end{bmatrix}
\\ &\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}
$$
so you are right, and the rank is 3. Must be a typo in the book.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Is the echelon form wrong? If so then what is the rank?

Comment: @MathLearner expanded out

Comment: @gt6989b, wouldn't it be easier to anihilate $2$ and $3$ in the $1^{\text{st}}$ row and then see that $2^{\text{nd}}$ and $3^{\text{rd}}$ column are linearly independent because they aren't proportional, which implies the full rank? Then we don't necessarily have to continue to get the canonical matrix. If we denote rows with $r$ and columns with $c$ we have $$\dim[\{r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4\}]=\dim[\{c_1,c_2,c_3\}]=3$$ and it satisfies the condition :$$\operatorname{rank}\le\min\{m,n\}$$

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya There is a variety of ways to do this, but American students are usually taught Gaussian Elimination straight up, I did not want to deviate from the way I thought the OP would think about such problems. You are absolutely correct, there are many more efficient ways of seeing this

Comment: @gt6989b, thank you for responding!